# next and prev in my script 

Tags: php, image, navigation, multipage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Previous/next Buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436017/previous-next-buttons)

how can i make next page and prev page in my gallery script .. 
when

```
mid = id of images 
path = link of images
```

I need two buttons: *next* to get next image and *prev* to get last image. How can i do it ?

```
$mid=$_GET['mid'];
$qur="select * from images where mid='$mid'";
$res=mysql_query($qur,$conn);
?>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>

<div class="gallery-img">
<a href="admin/<?php echo $row['path'] ?>" rel="prettyPhoto" class="portfolio-img" title="<?php echo $row['image_title'] ?>">
<img src="admin/<?php echo $row['path'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['image_title'] ?>" width="100%" height="100%" />
</a>
</div>  

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to write PHP code.

Comment: obvious SQL injection vulnerability hurts little baby jesus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `$_GET` I'm assuming this would be a dynamic page you go to to view a photo, which you want to show next and prev than on the page, if so than try this

```
<?php
$mid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['mid']);
$res=mysql_query("select * from images where mid='".$mid."'",$conn);
$prevSQL = mysql_query("SELECT mid, path FROM images WHERE mid > '".$mid."' LIMIT 1");
$nextSQL = mysql_query("SELECT mid, path FROM images WHERE mid < '".$mid."' LIMIT 1");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if(mysql_num_rows($prevSQL)>1){
    $prevRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($prevSQL);
    $prev = '<a href="admin/'.$prevRow['mid'].'">Prev</a>';
} else {
    $prev = 'Prev';
}
if(mysql_num_rows($nextSQL)>1){
    $nextRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($nextSQL);
    $next = '<a href="admin/'.$prevRow['mid'].'">Next</a>';
} else {
    $next = 'Prev';
}
?>
<div class="gallery-img">
<a href="admin/<?=$row['path'] ?>" rel="prettyPhoto" class="portfolio-img" title="<?=$row['image_title'] ?>">
<img src="admin/<?=$row['path'] ?>" alt="<?=$row['image_title'] ?>" width="100%" height="100%" />
</a>
<?=$prev.' '.$next;?>
</div>
```

Comment: please, do not feed [help vampires](http://www.slash7.com/pages/vampires)

Comment: @Bobby Thanks For Your Feedback  But i Have Question .. How can i make <?=$prev.' '.$next;?> In link ??

Comment: @afrogfx as shown in the above code, `$next` and `$prev` are all ready defined, so when you call `<?=$prev.' '.$next;?>`, you are calling on the links all ready created by the script. And if there is no next or prev it will just create the text with no link.

Comment: @Bobby  Thx Angie ... But I Want preview This code in HTML ?? i don't know how can i make next in link and perv in link ? <?=$prev.' '.$next;?> becouse when this code show ?? show without link just show Prev Prev

Comment: @Bobby I need my link Like It ?? but in html ? how can i make it <?=$prev.' '.$next;?> Like It ? 
<a href="THIS_PAGE_URL?mid=<?php '.($page-1).'?>">Prev</a>
<a href="THIS_PAGE_URL?mid=<?php '.($page+1).'?>">Next</a>